# In Eclipse (Java), how do I determine where an import is actually coming from?

Tags: java, eclipse

Say you're working on a Java project in Eclipse and you're looking at a `import` statement like:

```
import com.somefirm.somepackage.AClass;
```

and the classpath for the project has a million and one .jars on it.

How do you determine where the import is coming from?

Answer (score 15):

[Open declaration](http://help.eclipse.org/ganymede/topic/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.user/tasks/tasks-73.htm) (F3) on the import line. This will open the Java or Class file that the import resolves to.

Once that files is open, you can right-click on the declared type and choose "Show In->Package Explorer" to see where it is declared.

Alternately, if "Link with Editor" is selected in Package Explorer, the related package/jar will already be open for your inspection.

Answer (score 14):

I like to go to the `Navigate` menu, `Open Type...`   (or Ctrl-Shift-T is quicker), then type in the class name and see the list of possible jars where it could be coming from.  You can also use wildcards in the classname you type if you want to see some similarly-named and sometimes related classes.

Now if it lists more than one jar you'll have to try one the methods (F3 or F4) listed in the other answers here, but this is a quick way to see.   Worst case scenario is that you'll have more than one version of the same jar.

Answer (score 2):

And if the class is not found into your IDE you can use this resource to find classes in jars.
http://www.jarfinder.com/

Answer (score 2):

if you select the name `AClass` and hit `F4` which will bring up the class hierarchy, and the jar name will be on the status bar.

Answer (score 0):

Right-click on the import line and click on <kbd>Shown In</kbd> -> <kbd>Package Explorer</kbd>.

You can also right-click on the import line and click on <kbd>Show in Breadcrumb</kbd> if you just want to see the path.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/16507104)

Comment: @John Moutafis, I'm curious to know how this doesn't answer the question. I had the same query as the asker once, when I was working on a project spread across numerous classes and it was difficult to find the package from where the import was coming from in any class. Besides, my answer is a slight modification to what has been added by David Citron above.